# Add numbers from one table field to another?

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I want to know how can I add numbers from one table field to another for example, I have:

```
Table name = Game: 

opponent1(name of row) vs. opponent 2    -  score1 = 25 - score2 =  20
```

I would like  table "team" to update automatically with the following:

```
Table name = Teams: 

Opponent1: 

  Points in favor = 25
  Points against  = 20

Opponent 2: 

   Points in favor = 20
  Points against  = 25
```

What would be a code for that? Could it be (has some pseudocode):

- If score1 bigger than score2

  - Add score1 to "pointsfavor" field in table "team" to opponent1
  - And add $score2 to "pointsagainst" in table "team" to opponent1

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your tables have the following structure:

```
TABLE team
  id integer autoincrement primary key,
  name varchar,
  pointsfavor integer,
  pointscontra integer

TABLE game
  id integer autoincrement primary key,
  team1_id integer,
  team2_id integer,
  score1 integer, /*score for team1*/
  score2 integer /*score for team2*/
```

Your update statement might look something like this:

```
UPDATE team 
INNER JOIN game g1 ON (team.id = g1.team1_id)
INNER JOIN game g2 ON (team.id = g2.team2_id)
SET pointsfavor = pointsfavor 
      + IF(g1.score1 > g1.score2, g1.score1 - g1.score2, 0) 
      + IF(g2.score2 > g2.score1, g2.score2 - g2.score1, 0)
  , pointscontra = pointscontra 
      + IF(g1.score1 < g1.score2, g1.score2 - g1.score1, 0) 
      + IF(g2.score2 < g2.score1, g2.score1 - g2.score2, 0)
WHERE game.id = 10;
```

Comment: thnx! .. what does this do: WHERE game.id = 10;?

Comment: It only updates the score for game number 10, if you don't add a `where` clause it will keep on updating scores it has already processed, but if you update the scores as soon as a game is finished you don't need to keep track which games have had their scores processed.

Comment: So in game.id = "10" I substitute for "$ID" right? I'll reply for Johan, yes! (assuming that your "$ID" is actually the game table's id and not say, the team table's id, totally different things). Not a criticism, but DO learn basic SQL, you'll appreciate it soon enough...

Comment: @Norman, to expand on @virtualeyes, I'd recommend naming your variable `$game_id` so there is no room for confusion which id you're refering to, you'll pad yourself on the back for doing this when you'll look at your code 6 months later when you've forgotten all about those details which are so clear in your head right now.